# WSO2 clustering APIM and DAS with mysql,did not show stats with this error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

1. Clustering APIM divide into 4 part,publisher,store,keymanager, gataway. And use DAS for stats. Database is mysql.
2. I set the connection between APIM and DAS on publisher node.
3. When I invoke an api ,APIM console give error as below.

> ```
>  [2016-10-13 11:13:54,775] ERROR - APIMgtUsageHandler Cannot publish event. null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:124)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler.handleRequest(APIMgtUsageHandler.java:169)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:322)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
>         at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>         at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
>         at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:149)
>         at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [2016-10-13 11:13:54,807] ERROR - APIMgtResponseHandler Cannot publish response event. null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.publishEvent(APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher.java:140)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler.mediate(APIMgtResponseHandler.java:211)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
>         at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
>         at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
>         at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
>         at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>         at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:251)
>         at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: Which version of APIM and DAS you are using?

Comment: hi,Abimaran Kugathasan.My APIM is 1.10 and DAS is 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to slove this problem ,I get in touch with the dev of wso2.

rukshan gives me [this solution](http://rukspot.com/configure_wso2_apim_analytics_using_xml.html),configure DAS on api-manager.xml ,not on the UI.